# Maven accepting user-defined axis as plugin in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a Jenkins multi-configuration project and have added some user-defined axis variables.
I am running "Invoke top level maven" build and specifying goal as install.
Whenever I try to run the project, jenkins fails as build failure and gives error as:

```
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE  
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [INFO] Total time: 4.648 s  
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-09T15:30:02+05:30  
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/27M  
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix ''v120') -DMILESTONE=Alpha -DL=WTS -DGPU=HD4600 -DP=Win32 -DMINOR_NUMBER=0 -DSIGN_PWD=******** -DADMIN_PWD=******** -DT=v120 -DCustom_Path=C' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]  
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [ERROR]  
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.  
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [ERROR]  
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:  
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException  
[09-09-2015T15:43:47 IST] Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
```

Can anyone please help.

Here is my POM.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.jenkins.main</groupId>
  <artifactId>junitexample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>junitexample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <Exe.Name>${Msi.Name}</Exe.Name>
          <Installation_Type>${Installation_Type}</Installation_Type>
          <Custom_Path>${Custom_Path}</Custom_Path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>            
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you add your POMs files ?

Comment: @ShmulikKlein I have added my POM file.

Comment: Where do you use the property 'T' ? seems like you have a typo when executing a plugin (I guess, using prefix abbreviation). Can you please share in which module the error is happening ?

Comment: @ShmulikKlein Got it resolved, it was because of a plugin that I was using in Jenkins with Maven. Used alternate plugin and now able to run the tests. Thanks for the help.